# is there a way to access to NodeJS (V8) GC reference counts?

Tags: node.js, caching, garbage-collection

so i've implemented an experimental cache for my memory-hungry app, and thrown a heap into the mix so i can easily get the least accessed objects once the cache outgrows a certain limit—the idea is to purge the cache from objects that are likely not re-used any time soon and if so, retrieve them from the database.

so far, so fine, except there may be objects that have not yet been written to the database and should not be purged. i can handle that by setting a 'dirty' bit, no problem. but there is another source of problems: what if there are still valid references to a given, cached object lurking around somewhere? this may lead to a situation where function `f` holds a reference A to an object with an ID of `xxx`, which then gets purged from cache, and then another function `g` requests an object with the same ID of `xxx`, but gets *another* reference B, distinct from A. so far i'm building my software on the assumption that there should only ever be a single instance of any persisted object with a given ID (maybe that's stupid?).

my guess so far is that i could profit from a garbage-collection-related method like `gc.get_reference_count( value )`—checking that and knowing any count above `1` (since `value` is in the cache) means some closure is still holding on to `value`, so it should not be purged.

i haven't found anything useful in this direction. does the problem in general call for another solution?

Comment: i'm not sure it does... but it does have garbage collection, and didn't that used to use reference counts?

Comment: ok just read up on that and discovered V8 uses the generational approach... kind of a *reversal* of my cache's LRU strategy... so yeah maybe ref counts are out. the readup also proved that there are just 2 difficult things in CS, one of them being cache invalidation. guess i gotta dumb down my approach.